# Dialog is taking the whole screen width

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have made a custom Dialog

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dialog_text_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dialog_text_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dialog_text_padding">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_heading"
        tools:text="Permissions"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/brand_color"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_text"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="This app determines your phone location and shares it with Google to server personalized alters for you. This allows for a better app pferformance"/>





    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/okCancelView"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dialog_text_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dialog_text_padding"

       >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dialog_cancel"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dialog_text_padding"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            tools:text="OK"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:text="CANCEL"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/dialog_heading"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am showing it with simple

```
Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
d.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
d.show();
```

But my dialog is taking full width of the screen( image attached). Why is there no space between screen and dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Display display = ((Activity) ctx).getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            alert_dialog.getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .89),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: it will leave 10% space of width in both side

Comment: But the space is by default there. Whys its not coming in my case?

Comment: How do the dialogs in tablets appear? Do they take the full screen or they appear on just the middle part of screen?

Comment: That is default dialog. You are using custom dialog whose width is set to match_parent.

Comment: @Kunu even if i set it to wrap-content, its taking full width

Comment: You have to specify a width and height here for your parent LinearLayout (i.e for id `@+id/dialog_root`), and you can do that programmatically according to your screen also.

Comment: Yes. Programmatically i know i can do. And the method suggested my @DigveshPatel is good. I just wanted to know in case i am missing something here.

Comment: @Kunu can you please tell me if you know how do the default dialogs on tablets appear? Do they take the whole width or they are centered on the screen?

Comment: @Diffy just center on the screen